# Warning in GLM analysis

Tags: r

I was running GLM analysis using normalized and transformed data set but I encountered a Warning message as follow.

> glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
>   glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
>   glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Then, I created a simulation data frame and run it in the same fashion as I did for my actual data set and no warning. 
Below are my code and the simulation data set
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

````
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
data <- data.frame(B = c("m","m","m","m","m", "m", "f","f","f","f","f"),
                   G= c("s","s","s","u","u", "u", "k","k","k","r","r"),
                   g1 = c(35, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 41, 76), 
                   g2 = c(20, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 5, 3, 7, 2, 12), 
                   g3 = c(5, 0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 8, 9, 20, 1, 11,
                   g4 = c(1,3,4,5,7,3,1,5,7,3,10),
                   g5=  c(20,23, 27, 35, 12, 10, 17, 24, 21, 15, 16)))
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3)) %>% 
  group_split(name) %>% 
  set_names(nm = map(., ~ first(.x$name))) %>% 
  map(~ tidy(glm(factor(data$B) ~ value,family="binomial", data = .))) %>% 
  map(~ filter(., p.value > 0.05)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "var")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a problem with complete or quasi-complete separation: for some combination of your predictors you observed only successes of failures. That is a quite common phenomenon for logistic regression in small samples or if you have large parameter spaces.

There are several implementations that add a small penalty to the likelihood in order to get estimates for all parameters. Look up Firth logistic regression. In R that can be handled by the `logistf()` function from the `logistf` package.

Replace

```
glm(factor(data$B) ~ value,family="binomial", data = .)
```

in your code with

```
logistf(factor(data$B) ~ value, data = .)
```

and you should be up and running. (Remember to load the package first).

It should be noted that separation is not necessarily a problem in and of itself. Only if you want parameter estimates.

You can actually see the separation problem if you tabulate `B` against `G`:

```
xtabs(~ B + G, data=data)
```

This produces

```
   G
B   k r s u
  f 9 6 0 0
  m 0 0 9 9
```

So you can see that if you know, say, `G` then you know the outcome of `B`.

Comment: I used your code" logistf(factor(data$B) ~ value, data = .)" but it gave me an error "Error: No tidy method for objects of class logistf". Therefore, do you think the function" logistf" conflicts with "tidy"?

Comment: Yeah. `tidy()` probably hasn't wrappers that work with `logistf()`. You should still be able to get the necessary output using `summary()`. Perhaps it would be worth pinging the creators of `tidy()` and mention it to them?